# Blender Deform Modifiers: Trying to Bind Fiber Mesh (Pure Edges) to Cloth

Tags: modifiers, physics, geometry-nodes, cloth-simulation, hair

I've been playing with Blender 3.3's hair system. Off the suggestion from another question, I've been exploring combining cloth physics on a proxy fiber mesh and the hair deform Geometry Node which transfers the position attribute of every point in the fiber mesh back to the Hair Curve object.

Here is the node group in question:

[image: Simple Geometry Hair Deform Node Group]

I have gotten the physics to work on the cloth mesh, which I created by:

1. In Hair Curve Object, convert to Particles
2. From particle system, Convert to Mesh. This creates my fiber mesh.
3. Select all vertices in the fiber mesh and extrude (turns all the fiber edges to faces)

Running cloth sim on this works like a charm. The reason I have to do step 3 instead of running cloth sim on the fiber mesh is that it seems Blender's cloth sim collisions don't work with the fibers, and it needs faces. As I need collisions for long hair (properly spreading on the shoulders, for instance), this is unfortunately my only option, otherwise I would just stick to fiber mesh + cloth sim.

This would be the final solution, except that once I add faces to the hair mesh, I can no longer use the "Hair Deform" geometry node group. This is because modifying that mesh throws off the index of the points in the mesh so they are no longer 1:1 with the Hair Curves points.

Changing the transfer attribute mode to "Nearest" instead of "Index" does not work, unfortunately, because once the cloth mesh moves at all, Hair Curves object points that are not close to the points in the cloth mesh will simply disappear.

So I hatched this idea that I would perform physics on the cloth mesh, bind the original fiber mesh to the cloth mesh via some kind of modifier, and then I can have it both ways; the fibers will move according to physics, and the Hair Curves move according to the fiber, effectively appending working physics to the 3.3 Hair system.

However, I can not seem to figure out how to make the fiber mesh follow the cloth mesh. The Surface Deform requires faces, and the Mesh Deform seems to just crash when I try to do it.

Does anyone have any ideas? Could I maybe even hack the indices of the cloth mesh so that all of the new ones are indexed beyond the originals?

P.S. I forgot to mention this, but the reason I am not using the Particle Hair physics is because they simply do not work. I've tried on multiple hairstyles; they simply explode, no matter what settings are used. The hair root vertices also don't seem to actually stick to their original location when turning on collision, and pop off the scalp.